# Display site description instead of site name

Tags: multisite, description

I'm wondering how to display all the network sites in WP Multisite by displaying site description instead of site name. Below is the code provided by the expert in WP in this community. It's now displaying site name. What code should I change in order to make the list displaying all the sites with site description?

```
function wpse365255_print_sites() {
    $args = array(
        'number' => 10000, // if you've got more than 10,000 sites, 
                           //you can increase this
        'public'        => 1,
        'spam'          => 0,
        'deleted'       => 0,
        'archived'      => 0,
        'site__not_in'  => array( 1, 2 ), 
        // this will exclude sites with ID 1 and 2
    );
    $sites = get_sites( $args ); // will return an array of WP_Site objects 
    $list = '';
    foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
        $details = get_blog_details( $site->blog_id );
        if ( ! empty( $details ) ) {
            $list .= '<li>';
            $list .= '<a href="' . $details->siteurl . '">';
            $list .= $details->blogname;
            $list .= '</a>';
            $list .= '</li>';
        }
    }
    if ( ! empty( $list ) ) {
        echo '<ul>' . $list . '</ul>';
    }
}
```

I tried to change the `blogname` to `blogdescription` but the site description not showing up. I look forward to answers from the experts here. Thank you!

Comment: You may try changing `$details->blogname` to `get_blog_option( $site->blog_id, 'blogdescription')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[get_blog_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_blog_option/)
return blog info by supplying blog id and blog option name.
So you may try changing the blog name variable from

`$details->blogname` to `get_blog_option( $site->blog_id, 'blogdescription')`

in the loop

Becauae [get_blog_details()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_blog_details/) does not add the description from option to its output object. So it let is needed to manually fetch additional information.

By default, the get_blog_details() only returns the following details of the site

- blogname
- siteurl
- post_count
- home

Comment: Thanks, man! It works. :)

Comment: Glad it help. I have added notes on what get_blog_details() return so that people don't need to try and save some time.